# Data Loader 48.0 Installation error - Could not find install.bat

Tags: data-loader

Followed instructions here to install data loader

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=loader_install_windows.htm&type=5

Installed OpenJDK 11  from here
https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&os=&os=windows&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk

Getting error install.bat not found 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, ended up having to copy the dataloader.bat and the dataloader-48.0.0-uber.jar files from the Salesforce download, into the installed directory.  It now works ! Maybe a permissions issue with copying .bat files causes the initial install to fail.

Comment: Copying those files to the installed directory solved it for me -- thanks!

Comment: same here. copying the dataloader.bat and the dataloader-48.0.0-uber.jar files from the Salesforce download, into the installed directory worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Before downloading the data Loader, Understand some pre-requisite:-

### System Requirements

Data Loader is signed for Windows. To use Data Loader for Windows, you need:

- 64-bit
- 120 MB of free disk space
- 256 MB of available memory
- Zulu OpenJDK version 11

> NOTE Salesforce no longer bundles Java with the Data Loader for
>   Windows installer. Download and install Java on your Windows computer.
>   Salesforce recommend that you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the
>   directory where Zulu OpenJDK is installed. Doing so ensures that you
>   can run Data Loader in batch mode from the command line.

### Steps to download and install

1. Install Zulu OpenJDK version 11 before installing Data Loader.
2. From Setup, download the Data Loader installation file.
3. Right-click the .zip file and select Extract All.
4. In the Data Loader folder, double-click the install.bat file. If you
   get an unknown publisher error message, you can ignore it and run
   the file.
5. Specify where to install Data Loader, and select whether to
   overwrite an existing Data Loader installation.
6. Specify whether to create a Data Loader launch icon on your desktop
   or a start menu shortcut. Data Loader completes the installation.

Reference:-

1. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=loader_install_windows.htm&type=5
2. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=installing_the_data_loader.htm&type=5

### Installation Considerations

Over time, several versions of the Data Loader client application have been available for download. Some earlier versions were called “AppExchange Data Loader” or “Sforce Data Loader.” You can run different versions at the same time on one computer. However, do not install more than one copy of the same version. If you have installed the latest version and want to install it again, first remove the version on your computer.

Comment: Thanks Sanket. I followed all instructions as mentioned in the Salesforce documentation without success.  I only had one version of Data Loader v 44.0 on my machine. I had to uninstall it for some reason. New versin does not install correctly. I tried installing on a different machine too.